# How to do full text search in mongoosejs?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

What is the easier way to do a full text search with mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is an "ORM" for MongoDB. MongoDB has [some docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo) on full text search. However, MongoDB is not designed to be used for FTS, and big deployments typically use other tools like Solr or Sphinx.

If you're just trying to query with a regex, MongoDB [supports that](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions). The syntax should be similar in Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 2.4 contains experimental full text search capabilities: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes

There are a few mongoose keyword [plugins](http://plugins.mongoosejs.com/?q=keyword) for smaller scale stuff as well as an [elasticsearch](https://github.com/jamescarr/mongoosastic) plugin. http://plugins.mongoosejs.com is a great place to discover more.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out elastic search and mongoosastic.  Take a look

http://www.elasticsearch.org/

https://github.com/jamescarr/mongoosastic

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Semi-recent developments for those who come looking, both MongoDB and Mongoose allow for text searches now:

[What's new in Mongoose 3.8.9](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/05/09/whats-new-in-mongoose-3-8-9/)

[Example usage of text search](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/a-nodejs-perspective-on-whats-new-in-mongodb-2-6-part-i-text-search/)